# What is meant by "Lock packages" and when exactly it is used

Tags: package-management, opensuse, zypper

I moved to openSUSE recently. In their cheat sheet, there is a section called "Lock packages". Can someone explain for me what they are and  when they're used?

for example:  lock all packages starting with 'yast2'

```
zypper addlock yast2*
```

or

```
zypper al yast2*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an example is the easiest way to explain: 
we use cloud-init to deploy new instances within a private cloud. And for our environment we have to rely on a configuration which has been broken a couple of times during the development of cloud-init. So when we find a working cloud-init version we lock it. That way no update will break that version.

So in conclusion: whenever you need to keep a specific version of a package you would lock it for zypper.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you face some bugs or issues when updating certain packages. At the same time you want  patch or upgrade the rest packages.

*So, How to ignore updating certain packages?*

By locking them.